# Option for a plot via selectInput with quotations

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to generate a ggplot selecting the "position" variable via selectInput that contains a quotation within.

I have tried with paste0 or with differents combination of " and ', with lo luck.

on ui.R side:

```
selectInput("posicion","Visualizar Barras",
     list ("Agrupadas"= 'position_dodge2(preserve = "single")',
       "Sumadas"="stack")))
```

on server.R side:

```
output$g_virus_x_semana.1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(subset(v,  v$año==input$año.1 & Virus %in% input$virus), aes(semana, fill=Virus))+
        geom_bar(position = input$posicion, stat = "count")+
        scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)+
        scale_fill_virus()+theme_dark()+labs(y = "N° de virus identificados", x= "Semana")
```

If I select "Agrupadas", I'm getting: `` Error in : Can't find `position` called "position_dodge2(preserve = "single")" ``

Works like charm if a put the `position_dodge2(preserve = "single")` direct in de ggplot code section.

Comment: Wouldn't `position_dodge2` be a ggplot call? - This would be why it doesn't work inside `selectInput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make a reactive function based off of `input$posicion` to change the layer you add to the plot.

Your `selectInput()` could look like

```
selectInput(inputId = "posicion", label = "Visualizar barras",
                                    choices = list("Agrupadas",
                                                   "Sumadas") )
```

Then in the `server` you could add information about what layer to add to the plot based on the choice made. Notice the whole layer is stored in a list to add to the plot.

```
server = function(input, output) {

    bartype = reactive({
        if(input$posicion == "Agrupadas") {                     
            list( geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), stat = "count") )
            }
        else {
            list( geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "count") )
        }
    })

    # Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
    output$lineplot = renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(gear), fill = factor(cyl) ) ) +
            bartype()
    })

}
```

Comment: Nice solution!, have tried something similar without success, but the list was the missing part. Thanks!